# How can I create an empty java.util.UUID object?

Tags: java, scala, uuid

I don't know why I can't find the answer to this, but I need to pass a blank UUID object in one of my functions to represent a lack of UUID. What is the UUID analagous form of

```
val x: ""
```

, which would be an empty string. I'm essentially trying to get an empty UUID. I tried

```
UUID.fromString("")
```

but received an error, as you need a valid UUID string.

EDIT: I am implementing this in Scala.

Comment: UUID is defined as a 128-bit number and is canonically represented by 32 hex digits. A blank string is not a UUID, and I can't think of any meaningful way to convert it into one. So it's unclear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying it would be much better to use `Option[UUID]` instead, with `None` representing an empty UUID.

You can't use an empty `String`, as it does not conform to the UUID format, described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString()).

You *could* use

```
UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
```

Which would be the same as

```
new UUID(0L, 0L)
```

But the usage of that would be arbitrary, and it would be much better to signify the absence or lack of a `UUID` with `Option`.

Comment: Thanks! The `fromString` option is useful when integrating with a third-party API that requires a UUID but the value isn't actually used in a particular use case.

Answer (score 9):

Did you consider using Option[UUID] as a parameter type? In this case you can pass None to indicate lack of UUID. An empty string is not a valid guid that's why it is rejected by UUID.fromString

Comment: I was not aware you could pass in an optional parameter that way. You mean, for example func(Option[UUID]) instead of func(UUID)?

Comment: you can define your method as def method(uuidOpt : Option[UUID]) and call it either as method(None) or method(Option(UUID.fromString("<some valid uuid string here>")))